# Javascript - Removing last 3 words from a string

Tags: javascript, string

I've been able to find examples of how to remove the last word of a string, but in this instance I'm attempting to remove the last 3 words of a string. I've attempted this by adjusting some of the answers I've come across to remove a single word but none have gave me the expected results.

Example string `Highest ranked in the states`

I would like my return value be `Highest ranked`

Here are some code snippets of what I've attempted:

```js
let myString = "Highest ranked in the states";

myString = myString.substring(2, myString.lastIndexOf(" "));

console.log(myString)


let myString2 = "I want to remove the last word";
let mySplitResult2 = myString2.split(" ");
let lastWord =  mySplitResult2[mySplitResult2.length-3] 

console.log(lastWord)
```

with the adjusting the substring method to `(2, myString.lastIndexOf(" "));` it ended up removing the first two letters of my sentence and only removed the word `states` such as "guest ranked in the"

when adjusting the .split() method to length -3 it simply returns back the word `in` instead of `in the states`

Comment: `myString.split(' ').slice(-3)`

Comment: The answer above is the shortest and a better approach to the problem OP.

Comment: You could run "remove last word" that you already have 3 times, applying each next call to results of the previous one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a nice and readable one liner:

```js
const remove3words = words => words.split(" ").slice(0, -3).join(" ");

console.log(remove3words("Highest ranked in the states"));
console.log(remove3words("Exactly three words"));
```

---

You can generalize it easily to `n` words in the following way:

```js
function remove_n_words(words, n) {
    return n === 0 ? words : words.split(" ").slice(0, -n).join(" ");
}

// Test the function
console.log(remove_n_words("Highest ranked in the states", 0));
console.log(remove_n_words("Highest ranked in the states", 3));
console.log(remove_n_words("Highest ranked in the states", 100));
```

Answer (score 0):

See comments for explanation using split and splice

```js
let myString = "Highest ranked in the states";
//split the str using blank space between each word and add to new variable
let str = myString.split(" ");
//get the length 
let num = str.length;
//splice the array removing the last three values with the number - 3
let newStr = str.splice(0, num - 3);

let displayText = '';
//back into string
newStr.forEach(function(value){
  displayText += value + ' ';
});
display.textContent = displayText;
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myString = "Highest ranked in the states";

myString = myString.split(' ')
myString = myString.splice(myString.length-5,2)
myString = myString.join(' ')

console.log(myString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's **a function that can do that** for you. (It can actually remove all characters from the Nth-to-last occurrence of any character you specify, not just the Nth-to-last word.)

In your case:

- **the `char` parameter should get the value `' '`** (ie spaces between words)
- **`N` should get the value `3`** (to target the 3rd-to-last space)

I added an **`excludeChar` parameter that you can set to `true`** to avoid returning the final space (or you can use the `.trim` method on the result).

```js
const
  myString = "Highest ranked in the states",
  result = truncateAtNthToLastOccurencOfChar(myString, ' ', 3);
console.log(result);


function truncateAtNthToLastOccurencOfChar(str, char, N, excludeChar){

  // Makes counter,  converts str to arr & reverses it
  let i = -1, rev = Array.from(str).reverse();

  // Increments counter (and executes even when i=0)
  while(++i || true){

    // Returns original string if at the end `char` has occured fewer than `N` times
    if(i >= rev.length - 1){
      return str;
    }

    // If current character matches `char`, decrements `N`
    if(rev[i] == char && --N === 0){

      // If N=0, `i` is our target, all keeps characters (from reversed array)
      //   starting at `i` (or after `i` if excludeChar=true)
      return rev
        // The occurence of char can be excluded from result
        .slice(excludeChar ? (i + 1) : i)
        .reverse() // Restores original character order
        .join(''); // Converts back to string
    }
  }
}
```